# Get the drive program is running on in Mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, drive

I would like to find out the root of the drive that my Java application is running on in Mac. I have it working on Windows with the following code but I don't know how to make it work on OSx too:

```
// Method to determine and return the drive the application is running on
    public static String getDriveRunningOn(){
        // Get the root of all the drives attached to the computer
        File[] roots = File.listRoots();

        // Get the actual location of the application

        // Loop through the roots and check if any match the start of the application's running path
        for(int i = 0; i < roots.length; i++)
            if(getAppPath().startsWith(roots[i].toString())){
                String root = roots[i].toString();
                //if(root.endsWith(File.separator) && root.length() > 1) root = root.substring(0, root.length() - 1);
                return root;
            }

        // If the above loop doesn't find a match, just treat the folder the application is running in as the drive
        return "."; 
    }

    public static String getAppPath(){
        try{
            String appPath = MyCellRenderer.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
            appPath = URLDecoder.decode(appPath, "UTF-8");
            return new File(appPath).getAbsolutePath();
        }catch(Exception e){return "n/a";}
    }
```

So if the app was located in `C:\App.exe`, `getDriveRunningOn()` would output `C:\` and so on. I need the same to happen on Mac OSX. Thanks in advance

Comment: What application feature are you trying to implement?  Needing to find the drive the code is running on is usually an indication of going about providing a good feature, in a less than satisfactory way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Basically I want to display a list of all the Files on the drive irrespective of where the application is located. Is there a better way to do this - why is it not satisfactory?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but many hours running about the command line, most file systems are mounted under /Volmes/

Comment: *"Basically I want to display a list of all the Files on the drive irrespective of where the application is located."*  So I (as the end user who might want to see a list of files) would need to drag it to whatever drive I needed a file list on?  That sounds much less optimal than offering e.g. a list of files on the drive on which `user.home` is located, if not in `user.home` itself.  Of course, configurable from within the app., by me the user, to point to whatever drive I want it to.  Please expand on exactly what this program is, why it makes sense for it to be display file lists.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I suppose that option would seem more optimal, but providing that option would mess up what I already have and does not fit in with the objective and purpose of the application. Anyway, I've found a solution. I will post it in a minute.

Comment: Hopefully your solution will never need to be used in an applet or app. launched using JWS.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson It certainly won't be used in an applet or application made available with Java webstart by me! I really don't see what you have against what I am doing though.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of Unix file structure.  There is only one root.

Comment: @Steve-o Yes, there is a misunderstanding - I didn't realise there was only one root. Thanks for that information. I've only ever known Windows up to now when I've decided to dive in to Mac if I'm honest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so, it turns out on Mac `File.listRoots()` only lists `/`. I'm not sure whether this is because it only sees internal drives as 'roots' or what but that's what it does. Fortunately, in Mac, all drives/volumes attacthed (including USB drives, basically those listed in Computer) appear as folders in the `/Volumes` directory.

Therefore, I simply added an `if` statement in my `getDriveRunningOn()` method that, if on Mac, returns `new File("/Volumes").listFiles()` to the file array rather than `File.listRoots()`. Simples :)

Comment: Prepare for another `if` statement when you run your app on a Linux system. Hey, and what about Solaris ... . I would seriously consider @AndrewThompson suggestions

Comment: You have to remember, I am programming for a business, rather than personal reasons. Currently I am only targeting Windows and Mac for various reasons. If it were only for personal reasons I'd probably implement Andrew's suggestions but it's not, and  I do have a reason for doing what I am doing.